# How to change color of h2, h3, h4 in WordPress post

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have tried to change color of header of WordPress post. 
But this is not work. I am using feather magazine themes for [website](https://www.blogsurf.net).

Comment: `h2, h3, h4 { color: red; }` should do it

Comment: with !important;

Comment: the h1 to h6 tags are currently defined in the styles.css file from line 200 (according to dev tools). They're all set to black at the moment - so changing this will help you.

Comment: Hi, please post the code of what your have tried.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE].  Also, please read [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

```
.single_post .single-title {
    color: red;
}
```

should really only paint the post-title :)

Answer (score 0):

You could go to or use the source-view of the post (when editing).
Then find the `<h1>` `<h2>` or any heading element you want to change its color, then style it by e.g: `<h3 style="color: red;">Heading 3</h3>` for example.

If you host or have access to your wordpress installation, you could find your theme's folder, find the css file(s) that is applied to your blog. I couldn't remember the exact path example anymore. There is usually only one `style.css` file under the theme's css folder. Once you located the style.css file that applies to your blog, add a style to change the heading colors e.g:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: rgb(255,0,0); /* or use red as value */
}
```

or

```
<h1 class="differentcolor">Your classed heading</h1>

.differentcolor { color: red; } /* Your CSS */
```